# Randomizing lists with variables in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for a way to randomize lists in python (which I already know how to do) but to then make sure that two things aren't next to each other. For example, if I were to be seating people and numbering the listing going down by 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 based on tables but 2 people couldn't sit next to each other how would I make the list organized in a way to prohibit the 2 people from sitting next to each other.

Comment: simply check the shuffled list you know how to create for your condition. Did you try anything?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis O(∞)? :)

Comment: @timgeb If you construct the list instead to make sure it satisfies your condition, it is not actually random any more, is it? And i guess it is more like O(?).

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I'd call it random with respect to a constraint. You could create all the permutations of the list that satisfy the condition and then pick one randomly. One way is probably to construct a generator that enumerates these permutations and then create a random integer (edit: between 1 and #<allowed permutations>) and advance the generator as many times as that integer.

Comment: What two things shouldn't be next to each other? This is unclear.

Comment: @Alper 2 of the items in the list, sorry for not making this clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say that you know how to shuffle a list, the only requirement is that two elements are not next to each other.

A simple way is to:

- shuffle the full list
- if the two elements are close, choose a random possible position for the second one
- exchange the two elements

Maximum cost: one shuffle, one random choice, one exchange